# XSLT grouping by specific tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <InvoiceLines>
    <Lines>
      <LineNume>1</LineNume>
      <Description>Test1</Description>
      <Quantity>200</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>500</UnitPrice>
      <Amounts>
        <Net>100000</Net>
        <VATRate>
          <Percent>2</Percent>
        </VATRate>
        <VATAmount>2000</VATAmount>
        <Gross>102000</Gross>
      </Amounts>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <LineNume>2</LineNume>
      <Description>Test2</Description>
      <Quantity>300</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>1000</UnitPrice>
      <Amounts>
        <Net>300000</Net>
        <VATRate>
          <Percent>3</Percent>
        </VATRate>
        <VATAmount>9000</VATAmount>
        <Gross>309000</Gross>
      </Amounts>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <LineNume>3</LineNume>
      <Description>Test3</Description>
      <Quantity>100</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>500</UnitPrice>
      <Amounts>
        <Net>50000</Net>
        <VATRate>
          <Percent>3</Percent>
        </VATRate>
        <VATAmount>1500</VATAmount>
        <Gross>51500</Gross>
      </Amounts>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
      <LineNume>4</LineNume>
      <Description>Test4</Description>
      <Quantity>100</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>500</UnitPrice>
      <Amounts>
        <Net>50000</Net>
        <VATRate>
          <Excempt>0</Excempt>
        </VATRate>
        <VATAmount>0</VATAmount>
        <Gross>50000</Gross>
      </Amounts>
    </Lines>
  </InvoiceLines>
</Document>
```

And with this XSLT 1.0 code (updated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name ="kVAT" match="Amounts" use ="concat(generate-id(..), VATRate/Percent | VATRate/Excempt)" />

  <xsl:template match="Document/InvoiceLines">
    <xsl:variable name="NetAmount" select="Lines/Amounts/Net" />
    <xsl:variable name="VATAmount" select="Lines/Amounts/VATAmount" />
    <xsl:variable name="GrossAmount" select="Lines/Amounts/Gross" />
    <Summary>
      <xsl:for-each select=
                "//Amounts[generate-id() = 
                        generate-id(
                          key('kVAT', 
                              concat(generate-id(..), VATRate/Percent | VATRate/Excempt)
                          )[1]
                        )
                     ]">

        <xsl:variable name="keyGroup" select ="key('kVAT', concat(generate-id(..), VATRate/Percent | VATRate/Excempt))" />
        <Rate>
          <VATRate>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$keyGroup/VATRate/Percent">
                <Percent>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="$keyGroup/VATRate/Percent"/>
                </Percent>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <Excempt>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="$keyGroup/VATRate/Excempt"/>
                </Excempt>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </VATRate>
          <Net>
            <xsl:value-of select ="$keyGroup/Net" />
          </Net>
          <VATAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select ="$keyGroup/VATAmount" />
          </VATAmount>
          <Gross>
            <xsl:value-of select ="$keyGroup/Gross" />
          </Gross>
        </Rate>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <NetAmount>
        <xsl:value-of select ="sum($NetAmount)"/>
      </NetAmount>
      <VATAmount>
        <xsl:value-of select ="sum($VATAmount)"/>
      </VATAmount>
    </Summary>
    <GrossAmount>
      <xsl:value-of select ="sum($GrossAmount)"/>
    </GrossAmount>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have this result (updated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Summary>
    <Rate>
      <VATRate>
        <Percent>2</Percent>
      </VATRate>
      <Net>100000</Net>
      <VATAmount>2000</VATAmount>
      <Gross>102000</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
      <VATRate>
        <Percent>3</Percent>
      </VATRate>
      <Net>300000</Net>
      <VATAmount>9000</VATAmount>
      <Gross>309000</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
      <VATRate>
        <Percent>3</Percent>
      </VATRate>
      <Net>50000</Net>
      <VATAmount>1500</VATAmount>
      <Gross>51500</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
      <VATRate>
        <Excempt>0</Excempt>
      </VATRate>
      <Net>50000</Net>
      <VATAmount>0</VATAmount>
      <Gross>50000</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <NetAmount>500000</NetAmount>
    <VATAmount>12500</VATAmount>
  </Summary>
  <GrossAmount>512500</GrossAmount>
</Document>
```

But i need to group according to VAT rate and will have a result like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Summary>
    <Rate>
      <Net>100000</Net>
      <VATRate>
        <Percent>2</Percent>
      </VATRate>
      <VATAmount>2000</VATAmount>
      <Gross>102000</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
      <Net>350000</Net>
      <VATRate>
        <Percent>3</Percent>
      </VATRate>
      <VATAmount>10500</VATAmount>
      <Gross>360500</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <Rate>
      <Net>50000</Net>
      <VATRate>
        <Excempt>0</Excempt>
      </VATRate>
      <VATAmount>0</VATAmount>
      <Gross>50000</Gross>
    </Rate>
    <NetAmount>500000</NetAmount>
    <VATAmount>12500</VATAmount>
  </Summary>
  <GrossAmount>512500</GrossAmount>
</Document>
```

and please take note that the `<Rate/VATRate>` tag can have a child of `<percent>` or `<Excempt>` etc... into account.

I have spent a few days to solve this by finding similar topics but can seem to find any.

Can anyone please help me in solving this problem of mine using XSLT 1.0 only as we dont have access to other versions.

Thanks

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html There are also many examples of Muenchian grouping you can find here.

Comment: Hi Michael, tried to understand this Muenchian but seems a bit complicated, can you help me with this?

Comment: I tried the updated stylesheet, but cant seem to group accordingly, can anyone help me to fix it, thanks

Comment: Why are the grand totals of `NetAmount` and `VATAmount` inside `Summary`, but `GrossAmount` is outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="amt-by-rate" match="Amounts" use="VATRate/*" />

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <xsl:variable name="amounts" select="InvoiceLines/Lines/Amounts" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <Summary>
            <xsl:for-each select="$amounts[count(. | key('amt-by-rate', VATRate/*)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('amt-by-rate', VATRate/*)" />
                <Rate>
                    <Net>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($current-group/Net)"/>
                    </Net>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="VATRate"/>
                    <VATAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($current-group/VATAmount)"/>
                    </VATAmount>
                    <Gross>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($current-group/Gross)"/>
                    </Gross>
                </Rate>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Summary>
        <NetAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($amounts/Net)"/>
        </NetAmount>
        <VATAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($amounts/VATAmount)"/>
        </VATAmount>
        <GrossAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($amounts/Gross)"/>
        </GrossAmount>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```